# Turn a LED on and one off, with a single Reed switch

Tags: led, circuit-design

I would like to create a circuit in which a Reed switch is able to switch current between two LED. Is this possible without any IC or others components?

One led is on and one off, until the Reed switch is activated. I saw this working with 2 different load (led and lamp / led and motor) and I'm thinking If the same is possible with 2 LEDs.

5V used in the circuit.

I know there are 2 kind of Reed switch, and I do not care about which to use if it solve the problem. I anyway prefer to use the NO one.

Comment: (1) Please edit your question and add in the supply voltage as this will affect the answer. (2) Are you aware that reed switches come in "changeover" style? i.e., A normally open and normally closed contact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjqV61.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Simple LED selection using a changeover switch.*

> I do not care about which to use if it solve the problem.

Then the changeover type is the simplest solution. Either of the circuits of Figure 1 will work.